# Intermitent cc1plus.exe out of memory error

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

I see lots of hits on this error message in SO and elsewhere, but I dont think my situation has been covered yet. I can work for several hours on a very large Qt project and then get this message

```
cc1plus.exe:-1: error: out of memory allocating 65536 bytes
```

after a 'Rebuild', or sometimes just a 'Build' command. I am using the latest Qt, 5.15.0 in Qt Creator 4.12.1 in Win10 Pro 1909 with 16GB memory. I use the minGW compiler that installs with Qt, version 8.1.0. If I close Qt, sometimes it will work again for a while, but sometimes it takes a system reboot to get things going again.

I have added `CONFIG += resources_big` to my .pro file.
I have run the following batch file to make cc1plus.exe recognize large memory, with Visual Studio 2019 command-line tools:

```
REM Batch file to fix cc1plus out of memory errors.
REM Start this from the Visual Studio command prompt RUN AS ADMIN
bcdedit /set IncreaseUserVa 3072
cd C:\Pgms\Qt\5.15.0\Tools\mingw810_32\libexec\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\8.1.0
editbin.exe /LARGEADDRESSAWARE cc1plus.exe
```

**Can anyone shed some light on this? Why is it so intermittent.**

Comment: Yes, you can enable LARGEADDRESSAWARE. But I would prefer just a 64 Bit version...
I use this: https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: The http://winlibs.com/ build if MinGW-w64 was built with large address awareness.

Comment: I realize that this is not an issue with 64-bit compilation. I'm using 32-bit MinGW, sorry I did not include that in my query. This is a huge project, and it would be quite an effort to convert to 64-bit.